# Best practices to use az cli in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, azure-cli

I was wondering what is the prefered way how to login to az using

```
    az login
```

Because i have multiple jobs running on build node in parralel and they shouldnt be using same credentials

Edit: Currently I am overriding the AZURE_CONFIG_DIR so that it points to the current running job directory. But I don't see this in any examples so i was wondering if there is any better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, it seems you can use the service principals to login with Azure CLI command like this:

```
az login --service-principal --username client_id --password client_secret --tenant tenant
```

And you can use different service principles for different jobs, of course, you can assign different permissions to the different service principles.

Comment: but wont these information be exposed to some public folder that is usable by other job? If I do az login in one job... in another i wont have to even use az login. If I understand correctly there is only one az context

Comment: @MartinKosicky If you only want to log in once and also want to use different credentials for different jobs. Then it's impossible.

Comment: I want to be logged for one job, and want the other job to login for himself.

Comment: @MartinKosicky As I know, it's impossible.

Comment: what i did was to specify the AZURE_CONFIG_DIR in the withEnv section so each job has its own credentials and each job is force to az login, or was running az command in a docker container that was doing az jobs. But I was wondering if there are better solutions

Comment: @MartinKosicky The only way to change the credential each time when you run different jobs is to log in each time. There are no other ways as I know.

Comment: @MartinKosicky Any updates? If it's helpful to you?

Comment: Charles Xu I update the description. I am always doing login logout. However i am curious if settings AZURE_CONFIG_DIR  is the best practice if i want to have isolated build with isolated az accounts running in paralel

Comment: @MartinKosicky If you use the environment variable `AZURE_CONFIG_DIR`, it means you need to set it for each job at the beginning. And you also need to prepare the tokens for all the users before you run the jobs in parallel. Then use different directories for different users in different jobs with that environment variable.

Comment: @MartinKosicky Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.